# AdditionalTime in Find Routes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, route

I want to simulate a pizza delivery service for San Francisco.

Because delivering Pizza to homes is taking some time (giving the pizza to clients, waiting for the money, etc.) I thought that it may be interesting to add `AdditionalTime` to the delivery time.

In the Network Analyst Toolbox there is the [Find Routes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/network-analyst-toolbox/find-routes.htm) Tool, which should be able to do so.

It says, that AdditionalTime is "The amount of time spent at the stop, which is added to the total time of the route. The units for this attribute value are specified by the Measurement Units parameter. The attribute value is included in the analysis only when the measurement units are time based. The default value is 0."

But it doesn't say **how** or **where** to enter the additional time.

**Any Ideas?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Network Analyst, when you create a Route analysis, be sure to check under Analysis Settings that a Time Attribute is checked. You can also set Impedance to Minutes.

When you import Stops, use the field Attr_Minutes to enter the time impedance at the stop, or in your case, time spent at each house.